# SVG Bevel Effect on straight Paths

Tags: svg, inkscape, svg-filters

I'm using Inkscape to draw a piping diagram, i'm trying to make the pipes have some sort of bevel effect. I partially succeeded, however, whenever the path is a straight line, the path disappears. I'm not sure why the filter would be doing that. It looks like the path have some sort of bounding box, and it cuts the canvas whenver it's a strigh line, I tried to show it as it happens by shifting the starting node of the line.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:osb="http://www.openswatchbook.org/uri/2009/osb"
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="297mm"
   height="210mm"
   viewBox="0 0 1052.3622 744.09448"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.91 r13725"
   sodipodi:docname="drawing.svg">
  <defs
     id="defs4">
    <linearGradient
       id="linearGradient8399"
       osb:paint="solid">
      <stop
         style="stop-color:#b00000;stop-opacity:1;"
         offset="0"
         id="stop8401" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient
       id="linearGradient8379"
       osb:paint="solid">
      <stop
         style="stop-color:#000000;stop-opacity:1;"
         offset="0"
         id="stop8381" />
    </linearGradient>
    <marker
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow1Lstart"
       orient="auto"
       refY="0"
       refX="0"
       id="Arrow1Lstart"
       style="overflow:visible"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         id="path4402"
         d="M 0,0 5,-5 -12.5,0 5,5 0,0 Z"
         style="fill:#0088ab;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#0000ab;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         transform="matrix(0.8,0,0,0.8,10,0)"
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    </marker>
    <marker
       inkscape:stockid="Arrow1Lend"
       orient="auto"
       refY="0"
       refX="0"
       id="Arrow1Lend"
       style="overflow:visible"
       inkscape:isstock="true">
      <path
         id="path4405"
         d="M 0,0 5,-5 -12.5,0 5,5 0,0 Z"
         style="fill:#0088ab;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#0000ab;stroke-width:1pt;stroke-opacity:1"
         transform="matrix(-0.8,0,0,-0.8,-10,0)"
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    </marker>
     <filter inkscape:label="Bevel1" id="Bevel" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="-10%" y="-10%" width="150%" height="150%">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3" result="blur"/>
    <feSpecularLighting in="blur" surfaceScale="5" specularConstant="0.5" specularExponent="10" result="specOut" lighting-color="white">
      <fePointLight x="-5000" y="-10000" z="20000"/>
    </feSpecularLighting>
    <feComposite in="specOut" in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in" result="specOut2"/>
    <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="specOut2" operator="arithmetic" k1="0" k2="1" k3="1" k4="0" result="litPaint" />
  </filter>
  <filter inkscape:label="Bevel2" id="Bevel2" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="-10%" y="-10%" width="150%" height="150%">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="0.5" result="blur"/>
    <feSpecularLighting in="blur" surfaceScale="5" specularConstant="0.5" specularExponent="10" result="specOut" lighting-color="white">
      <fePointLight x="-5000" y="-10000" z="0000"/>
    </feSpecularLighting>
    <feComposite in="specOut" in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in" result="specOut2"/>
    <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="specOut2" operator="arithmetic" k1="0" k2="1" k3="1" k4="0" result="litPaint" />
  </filter> 
    <filter
       inkscape:label="Pipe"
       inkscape:menu="Bevels"
       inkscape:menu-tooltip="Soft bevel, slightly depressed middle"
       style="color-interpolation-filters:sRGB"
       id="filter4992">
      <feGaussianBlur
         stdDeviation="2.3"
         in="SourceAlpha"
         result="result0"
         id="feGaussianBlur4994" />
      <feMorphology
         in="SourceAlpha"
         radius="6.6"
         result="result1"
         id="feMorphology4996" />
      <feGaussianBlur
         stdDeviation="8.9"
         in="result1"
         id="feGaussianBlur4998" />
      <feColorMatrix
         values="1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0.3 0"
         result="result91"
         id="feColorMatrix5000" />
      <feComposite
         in="result0"
         operator="out"
         result="result2"
         in2="result91"
         id="feComposite5002" />
      <feGaussianBlur
         stdDeviation="1.7"
         result="result4"
         id="feGaussianBlur5004" />
      <feDiffuseLighting
         surfaceScale="3.01699996"
         id="feDiffuseLighting5006">
        <feDistantLight
           azimuth="225"
           elevation="45"
           id="feDistantLight5008" />
      </feDiffuseLighting>
      <feBlend
         in2="SourceGraphic"
         mode="multiply"
         id="feBlend5010" />
      <feComposite
         in2="SourceAlpha"
         operator="in"
         result="result3"
         id="feComposite5012" />
      <feComposite
         in2="result3"
         operator="atop"
         id="feComposite5018" />
    </filter>
    <clipPath
       clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
       id="clipPath8692">
      <path
         d="M 0,560 960,560 960,0 0,0 0,560 Z"
         id="path8694"
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    </clipPath>
    <linearGradient
       x1="0"
       y1="0"
       x2="1"
       y2="0"
       gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
       gradientTransform="matrix(9,0,0,-9,310,400)"
       spreadMethod="pad"
       id="linearGradient8656">
      <stop
         style="stop-opacity:1;stop-color:#cccccc"
         offset="0"
         id="stop8658" />
      <stop
         style="stop-opacity:1;stop-color:#666666"
         offset="0.516129"
         id="stop8660" />
      <stop
         style="stop-opacity:1;stop-color:#cccccc"
         offset="1"
         id="stop8662" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient
       x1="0"
       y1="0"
       x2="1"
       y2="0"
       gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
       gradientTransform="matrix(4.0585937,0,0,-4.0585937,312.9707,400.18848)"
       spreadMethod="pad"
       id="linearGradient8678">
      <stop
         style="stop-opacity:1;stop-color:#808080"
         offset="0"
         id="stop8680" />
      <stop
         style="stop-opacity:1;stop-color:#666666"
         offset="0.516129"
         id="stop8682" />
      <stop
         style="stop-opacity:1;stop-color:#808080"
         offset="1"
         id="stop8684" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient
       x1="0"
       y1="0"
       x2="1"
       y2="0"
       gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
       gradientTransform="matrix(4,0,0,-4,313,408.5)"
       spreadMethod="pad"
       id="linearGradient8716">
      <stop
         style="stop-opacity:1;stop-color:#808080"
         offset="0"
         id="stop8718" />
      <stop
         style="stop-opacity:1;stop-color:#666666"
         offset="0.516129"
         id="stop8720" />
      <stop
         style="stop-opacity:1;stop-color:#808080"
         offset="1"
         id="stop8722" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient
       x1="0"
       y1="0"
       x2="1"
       y2="0"
       gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
       gradientTransform="matrix(-3e-7,7,7,3e-7,314.69287,405)"
       spreadMethod="pad"
       id="linearGradient8738">
      <stop
         style="stop-opacity:1;stop-color:#4d4d4d"
         offset="0"
         id="stop8740" />
      <stop
         style="stop-opacity:1;stop-color:#000000"
         offset="0.516129"
         id="stop8742" />
      <stop
         style="stop-opacity:1;stop-color:#4d4d4d"
         offset="1"
         id="stop8744" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient
       inkscape:collect="always"
       xlink:href="#linearGradient8656"
       id="linearGradient7559"
       gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
       gradientTransform="matrix(9,0,0,-9,310,400)"
       spreadMethod="pad"
       x1="0"
       y1="0"
       x2="1"
       y2="0" />
    <linearGradient
       inkscape:collect="always"
       xlink:href="#linearGradient8678"
       id="linearGradient7561"
       gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
       gradientTransform="matrix(4.0585937,0,0,-4.0585937,312.9707,400.18848)"
       spreadMethod="pad"
       x1="0"
       y1="0"
       x2="1"
       y2="0" />
    <linearGradient
       inkscape:collect="always"
       xlink:href="#linearGradient8716"
       id="linearGradient7563"
       gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
       gradientTransform="matrix(4,0,0,-4,313,408.5)"
       spreadMethod="pad"
       x1="0"
       y1="0"
       x2="1"
       y2="0" />
    <linearGradient
       inkscape:collect="always"
       xlink:href="#linearGradient8738"
       id="linearGradient7565"
       gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
       gradientTransform="matrix(-3e-7,7,7,3e-7,314.69287,405)"
       spreadMethod="pad"
       x1="0"
       y1="0"
       x2="1"
       y2="0" />
    <symbol
       id="symbol7344">
      <g
         id="g8961"
         transform="translate(-12.857143,-45)">
        <g
           transform="matrix(10.322682,0,0,-9.3703008,-2818.9541,4376.9346)"
           id="g8644">
          <g
             id="g8646">
            <g
               id="g8652">
              <g
                 id="g8654">
                <path
                   inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
                   id="path8664"
                   style="fill:url(#linearGradient7559);stroke:none"
                   d="m 314.539,400.13 -4.539,2.211 0,-4.682 4.593,1.834 4.407,-1.834 0,4.682 -4.461,-2.211 z" />
              </g>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
        <g
           transform="matrix(9.3703008,0,0,-9.3703008,-2523.716,4376.9346)"
           id="g8666">
          <g
             id="g8668">
            <g
               id="g8674">
              <g
                 id="g8676">
                <path
                   inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
                   id="path8686"
                   style="fill:url(#linearGradient7561);stroke:none"
                   d="m 312.97,400.189 c 0,-1.122 0.909,-2.03 2.03,-2.03 l 0,0 c 1.121,0 2.029,0.908 2.029,2.03 l 0,0 c 0,1.12 -0.908,2.028 -2.029,2.028 l 0,0 c -1.121,0 -2.03,-0.908 -2.03,-2.028" />
              </g>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
        <g
           transform="matrix(9.3703008,0,0,-9.3703008,-2519.716,4376.9346)"
           id="g8688">
          <g
             clip-path="url(#clipPath8692)"
             id="g8690">
            <g
               transform="translate(309.5,404)"
               id="g8696" />
            <g
               transform="translate(319.5,404)"
               id="g8700">
              <path
                 inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
                 id="path8702"
                 style="fill:none;stroke:#c1272d;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
                 d="M 0,0 0,-9" />
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
        <g
           transform="matrix(9.3703008,0,0,-9.3703008,-2523.716,4376.9346)"
           id="g8704">
          <g
             id="g8706">
            <g
               id="g8712">
              <g
                 id="g8714">
                <path
                   inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
                   id="path8724"
                   style="fill:url(#linearGradient7563);stroke:none"
                   d="m 313,412.535 0,-9.535 4,0 0,9.535 c 0,0 -0.292,1.465 -2.041,1.465 l 0,0 C 313.21,414 313,412.535 313,412.535" />
              </g>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
        <g
           transform="matrix(9.3703008,0,0,-9.3703008,-2523.716,4376.9346)"
           id="g8726">
          <g
             id="g8728">
            <g
               id="g8734">
              <g
                 id="g8736">
                <path
                   inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
                   id="path8746"
                   style="fill:url(#linearGradient7565);stroke:none"
                   d="m 312.335,412 c -1.859,0 -3.366,-1.641 -3.366,-3.5 l 0,0 c 0,0 0,1.859 0,0 l 0,0 c 0,-1.859 1.507,-3.5 3.366,-3.5 l 0,0 4.716,0 c 1.859,0 3.366,1.641 3.366,3.5 l 0,0 c 0,1.859 -1.507,3.5 -3.366,3.5 l 0,0 -4.716,0 z" />
              </g>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
      <rect
         style="fill:currentColor;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none"
         id="rect8397"
         width="10.714286"
         height="90"
         x="357.85715"
         y="543.79077" />
    </symbol>
  </defs>
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="1.4"
     inkscape:cx="278.01149"
     inkscape:cy="501.16844"
     inkscape:document-units="px"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:window-width="1920"
     inkscape:window-height="1003"
     inkscape:window-x="-9"
     inkscape:window-y="-9"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     fit-margin-top="0"
     fit-margin-left="0"
     fit-margin-right="0"
     fit-margin-bottom="0"
     units="mm" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata7">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(4.0999855,121.23227)">
    <path
       style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#0012ff;stroke-width:12.89999962;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;filter:url(#filter4992)"
       d="m 52.14287,-19.780663 c 185.81573,-1.274494 96.29616,30.57495 255.99999,96.428577"
       id="path4712"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       sodipodi:nodetypes="cc" />
    <path
       style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#0012ff;stroke-width:12.89999962;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;filter:url(#filter4992)"
       d="m 234.49999,188.43361 159.99999,0.14286 0,154.14286 81,0 0,186.42857"
       id="path4712-3"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccc" />
    <use
       xlink:href="#symbol7344"
       id="use7373"
       class="yellow"
       transform="translate(-19.285714,-17.142857)"
       x="0"
       y="0"
       width="100%"
       height="100%" />
    <use
       id="use7439"
       xlink:href="#symbol7344"
       x="0"
       y="0"
       width="100%"
       height="100%"
       transform="translate(-298.3187,-17.276789)" />
    <rect
       style="fill:#0000ff;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1;"
       id="rect8227"
       width="111.42857"
       height="117.85714"
       x="346.61432"
       y="12.147933" />
    <path
       style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#0012ff;stroke-width:13;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;"
       d="m 42.328585,132.86221 156.428565,0 0,0"
       id="path8231"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: This looks fine on Chrome - where are you having the problem

Comment: @MichaelMullany it does actually, but not in Firefox, IE, and most importantly Inkscape own editor.

Comment: Looks ok on IE 11 as well

Comment: What version of inkscape are you using?

Comment: @Josiah  its inkscape 0.91

Comment: Looks fine in Firefox 35/Windows 8.1 & Inkscape 0.48.4

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that by default SVG filters are applied to the bounding box of the object that they are applied to, this doesn't include the stroke.

For a horizontal or vertical line, this results in the filter not working as you might expect.

As a quick workaround for firefox, you can add the following attributes to each of the filter nodes in the XML:

```
   filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
   x="-500"
   y="-500"
   width="1000"
   height="1000"
```

This doesn't appear to work in Inkscape. Also I believe it results in an unnecessarily large filter area, decreasing this as much as possible will lessen the time needed to render the image.